# Extract parts from object and create new reduced version

Tags: underscore.js

I have an JavaScript object I need to extract parts of and then create a new object array. The main thing to note is that the key names are different in the new object (it's for Google Tag Manager and the key names have been predefined).

I would like to use underscore.js as it's already being used heavily in this project, but it's not essential if a vanilla JS solution is simpler.

**This is a simplified version of the existing object**

```
{
   'object_handle': 'handle',
   'something_else': 'ladela',
   'some_other_thing': 'other thing',
   'data':{
      'object_id': 120,
      'buildings':[
         {
            'item_id':120,
            'title':'Some title',
            'not_needed': 'Don't need this',
            'locations':[
               {
                  'location_id':4444
               }
            ]
         }, 
         {
            'item_id':121,
            'title':'Some other title',
            'not_needed': 'Don't need this',
            'locations':[
               {
                  'location_id':5555
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            'item_id':122,
            'title':'Some different title',
            'not_needed': 'Don't need this',
            'locations':[
               {
                  'location_id':6666
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**I would like to extract parts (from data.buildings) and create this new object array**

```
[{
    'name': 'Some title',
    'id': '120',
    'location': '4444'
},
{
    'name': 'Some other title',
    'id': '121',
    'location': '5555'
},
{
    'name': 'Some different title',
    'id': '122',
    'location': '6666'
}]
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

If it helps, I have created a Fiddle with the data - https://jsfiddle.net/e7t8ypmd/2/

Comment: Run a `map` over `data.buildings`.

Comment: This worked great - https://jsfiddle.net/e7t8ypmd/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

I considered var a as your object...

```js
var a ={your object};

var b = _.each(a.data.buildings, function (item) {
                    item.name = item.title;
                    item.id = item.item_id;
                    item.location = item.locations[0].location_id;
                });

var plucked = b.map(function (model) {
                    return _.pick(model, ["name", "id","location"]);
                });
```

variable 'plucked' will have only the required properties.